# iPhone: Modify a cell selected in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a table with entries which the user can select and when clicking on them the UILabel should turn to a UITextField so the user can edit the value of that row.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.section == 1 &&
       indexPath.row < [item.entries count])
    {
        ListDetailCell *tmpCell = ((ListDetailCell*)[self tableView:tvEntries cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]);
        tmpCell.lbTitle.hidden = true;  // <- cell to hide
        tmpCell.tfTitle.hidden = false; // <- textfield to show
    }
}
```

For any reasons it seems that my changes on the controls don't get applied.

Any hints here?
Thx in advance

Comment: I don't know if it's appropriate in your situation, but couldn't you simply use a UITextField with a placeholder instead of a UILabel?

Comment: Yes i already thought about this. But as far as i know i cannot make a text field look like a plain label (w/o border)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was at last to insert an additional flag which tells me, if I'm in edit-mode or not. In cellForRowAtIndexPath i'm checking this flag and set visibility of Label/Textfield.

Not really a proper way but it saved me from spending some more hours on this topic.

Thx for your suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` after applying your updates?  Like:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.section == 1 &&
       indexPath.row < [item.entries count])
    {
        ListDetailCell *tmpCell = ((ListDetailCell*)[self tableView:tvEntries cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]);
        tmpCell.lbTitle.hidden = true;  // <- cell to hide
        tmpCell.tfTitle.hidden = false; // <- textfield to show

        //reload the cell
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObject: indexPath]
         withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }
}
```

In general, updates made to a displayed cell will not appear unless you explicitly tell the table to reload that cell (or to reload everything by calling `reloadData`.

Comment: despite of the fact, i hadn't connected my UITextField, the reload of the cell (i tried `reloadData`, `reloadInputViews` and `reloadRowsAtIndexPath`) didn't work for me.